# Specific json string formatting

Tags: angularjs, json

I have an odd requirement to prettify a JSON structure in a very precise way.  Currently I'm using angular.toJson(jsonObj, true) to auto-prettify it.

However, how could I do customized formatting.  Given the following JSON:

```
  {"SomeArray": [
    {
      "Description": "Some sort of description",
      "a": 0,
      "b": "foo0",
      "c": "bar0"
    },
    {
      "a": 0,
      "b": "foo1",
      "c": "bar1",
      "d": "DoSomething1"
    },
    {
      "a": 0,
      "b": "foo2",
      "c": "bar2",
      "d": "DoSomething2"
    },
    {
      "Description": "Another description",
      "a": 0,
      "b": "foo3",
      "c": "bar3",
      "d": "DoSomething3"
    },
    {
      "a": 0,
      "b": "foo4",
      "c": "bar4",
      "d": "DoSomething4"
    }]}
```

How can I format this to look exactly like the following?  Basically I need to keep "description" keys on it's own seperate line, while the other keys are on a line immediately below it, as well as keeping the curly brace on the same line as well:

```
{"SomeArray": [
    { "Description": "Some sort of description",
      "a": 0, "b": "foo0", "c": "bar0" },
    { "a": 0, "b": "foo1", "c": "bar1", "d": "DoSomething1" },
    { "a": 0, "b": "foo2", "c": "bar2", "d": "DoSomething2" },
    { "Description": "Another description",
      "a": 0, "b": "foo3", "c": "bar3", "d": "DoSomething3" },
    { "a": 0, "b": "foo4", "c": "bar4", "d": "DoSomething4" }]}
```

Comment: If you could explain why you need to format the string that explicitly?

Formatting and layout is not the job of JSON. I'd suggest that you'd be better off using some form of presentation technology (even simple HTML tables) to create the desired layout.

Comment: It's just a requirement I was tasked with.  Need to have the json in a file formatted exactly that way.  It's for some human readability requirements apparently.

Comment: I really think then that you're going to struggle to find an efficient and maintainable solution. The only potential solution I can think of is to write a 'custom formatter' function to take the string, find occurrences of things like '[' and whatever identifiers you have for structuring your format and do string.replace to insert newline and tab (probably \n and \t) to your string. Even then it may not work consistently!

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured.  Thanks much anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured I'd circle back around and answer how I wound up solving this.  Just wound up using HandleBars.js.  It's a pretty slick templating engine.  I wrote the template of how I want json output to look, then just passed it the object I wanted formatted.  The net results was formatting exactly as I needed it, with very little effort!

If anyone else is struggling with formatting JSOn for whatever reason, I strongly recommend checking out Handlebars.